# SWT PrintDialog driver preferences / customize the printdialog

Tags: swt, driver, preferences, printdialog

I would like to create a custom SWT PrintDialog. However it seems not possible.

In SWT PrintDialog one can click "preferences" to open the native printer driver preferences dialog. Is it possible to open the "native printer driver preferences dialog" without using org.eclipse.swt.printing.PrintDialog and read the drivers preferences (PrinterData)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PrintDialog` is very platform specific. The Mac version, for example, does not have a Preferences option. The class contains a lot of undocumented low level code interfacing to a particular platform. It is possible to use the low level code in your own class but this is not supported and you would need some experience of the platform API.

Just to illustrate the difference, here is the first few lines of the `open` method on Windows:

```java
public PrinterData open() {
    /* Get the owner HWND for the dialog */
    Control parent = getParent();
    int style = getStyle();
    long /*int*/ hwndOwner = parent.handle;
    long /*int*/ hwndParent = parent.handle;
```

and the Mac OS X code:

```java
public PrinterData open() {
    PrinterData data = null;
    NSPrintPanel panel = NSPrintPanel.printPanel();
    NSPrintInfo printInfo = new NSPrintInfo(NSPrintInfo.sharedPrintInfo().copy());
    if (printerData.duplex != SWT.DEFAULT) {
        long /*int*/ settings = printInfo.PMPrintSettings();
```

and Linux:

```java
public PrinterData open() {
    if (OS.GTK_VERSION < OS.VERSION (2, 10, 0)) {
        return Printer.getDefaultPrinterData();
    } else {
       byte [] titleBytes = Converter.wcsToMbcs (null, getText(), true);
       long /*int*/ topHandle = getParent().handle;
        while (topHandle != 0 && !OS.GTK_IS_WINDOW(topHandle)) {
            topHandle = OS.gtk_widget_get_parent(topHandle);
        }
```

Comment: when I look in http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/eclipse/swt/printing/PrintDialog.java.html lines 394-408 it seems that it is only the OS.DM_ORIENTATION (landscape, portrait) that is retrieved from the actual driver-settings and this being cross-platform, but this can be set manually. If I understand correctly the "PRINTDLG pd = new PRINTDLG();" line 265 is the platform specific part of the PrintDialog. Ok, then I would have to know what to look for at each platform to keep my code cross-platform. Thank you for answering. I will try something else :)

Comment: The whole of PrintDialog is platform specific, the Mac version (in a different jar) is **completely** different.